# Proof of a non context free language

Tags: context-free-grammar

I am trying to prove that $$\{u\#v\,|\,u,v\in\{0,1\}^∗ \text{and }u \text{ is a substring of }v\}$$ is not context free. Is it possible for a subset of a non-context free language to be context-free?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: *Is it possible for a subset of a non-context free language to be context-free?* Yes: take the empty subset of any non-context free language.